# Get Google Analytics API token / Google_Client getAccessToken returns null / empty

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to get a Google access token for a service account so I can access the Analytics API from the client side.

On the server side I have the following code:

```
    $keyFile = base_path() . '/keys/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx.json';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Analytics Demo');
    $client->setAuthConfig($keyFile);
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);

    $token = $client->getAccessToken();  // Returns null
```

At some point it returned a token, but after a couple of calls it started returning `null`.

Trying to get the `$client->getRefreshToken()` also returns null.

When I put `$client` in a `Google_Service_Analytics` object everything seems to work just fine, so I know the key file is correct and properly read:

```
    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts(); // Returns proper data
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

UPDATE:

Calling `$client->isAccessTokenExpired()` results in true so I guess I have to refresh the token, but I have no clue how.

Comment: Im curios as to why you need the access token. If this is a service account it should automatically be refreshing it for you as needed.

Comment: @DalmTo I need the token to send to the client side so it can embed analytics graphs

Comment: Let me guess your trying to link the embeded api to a service account?

Comment: indeed, seems to work fine witth the `fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion`. I've updated the answer with a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I found that I had to use `$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()` instead of `$client->getAccessToken()`.

```
public static function getGoogleServiceToken():?string {
    $keyFile = base_path() . '/keys/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.json';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($keyFile);
    $client->setApplicationName('Analytics Demo');
    $client->setAccessType('access_type');
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);

    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
    }
    else {
        $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    }

    return $token['access_token'];
}
```

Client side:

```
...
private _handleGetResponse(response) {
    ...
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
            serverAuth: {
                access_token: response.token,
            }
        });
    ...
```

Not sure why there is no decent documentation on this at all. Even knowing that I have to use this method I can't find documentation on what this method is actually doing. Any explanation or links to some documentation are still welcome!

Comment: @DalmTo https://doub1ejack.github.io/vendor/google/apiclient/phpdoc/classes/Google_Client.html#method_refreshTokenWithAssertion it says: "For backwards compatibility alias for fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion".. seems that `fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion` replaces `refreshTokenWithAssertion`. Both seem to work fine

Comment: Think thats the other way around if you check the actual client library not sure what site that is you are looking at. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/9ab9cc07f66e2c7274ea2753f102ae24d1271410/src/Google/Client.php#L225

Comment: `fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion` is the actual implementation (so the new one). `refreshTokenWithAssertion` is the depricated one