# Google Drive API Push Notifications - getting Invalid Credentials error when trying to use JWT token

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to set up Push Notifications to a PHP webhook endpoint for my Google Drive account.

First, I followed instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push

This resulted in me verifying my domain and registering it in Search Console. All seems well. And in this stage I received a JSON file with following data:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "mywebapp",
  "private_key_id": "myprivatekey",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----somelongkey-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "somemeail@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "someclientid",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/mywebapp%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Then in order to set up a `watch channel`, in a PHP script I have

```
$service_account_email = "myserviceaccount@mywebapp.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
$private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----somelongkey-----\n";
$uid = 'someid';
$is_premium_account = false;

$now_seconds = time();
$payload = array(
    "iss" => $service_account_email,
    "sub" => $service_account_email,
    "aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
    "iat" => $now_seconds,
    "exp" => $now_seconds+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
    "uid" => $uid,
    "claims" => array(
        "premium_account" => $is_premium_account
    )
);

$token = JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, "RS256");

// now set up watch channel
$body =  [
    'id' => uniqid(),
    'type' => 'web_hook',
    'address' => 'https://mywebhookendpoint'
];
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$result = $client->post('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch', [
    'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json',  "Authorization: Bearer ".$token ],
    'base_uri' => "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch",
    'body' => json_encode($body)
]);
```

When I do above, I get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials" (truncated...)
```

When I debug the call in PHPStorm, I see that a token is created, and that it expires one hour from the current time. And in general, all 'seems' well.

I suspect I am fundamentally taking the wrong approach, which wouldn't surprise me, since I have never tried this before, and the Google docs seem so cryptic about how all the various parts of the authentication puzzle fit together, especially when/where Oauth is required, when/where a service account suffices, where/when a JWT token works.

How can I overcome the above error?

Comment: Why dont you use the google api php client library?

Comment: Ended up doing just that in the end (my current approach is in answer below)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got to the bottom of this...

First, I have to say, Google API documentation is at times like a labyrinth weaving through a hall of mirrors in a zero gravity environment...

Noticed here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth

that "Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests"

So I scrapped above approach and read up more specifically on Google OAuth via service accounts, specifically using PHP, via

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Here is how I am successfully getting authorization token. Below assumes using composer.json, with entry like `"require": { "google/apiclient": "^2.0"}`

```
function getClient()
{
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Some Name');
    $client->setAuthConfig( __DIR__  . '/serviceaccount.json');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    return ['client'=>$client, 'token'=> $token['access_token']];
}
```

Apparently, the `Then, from here I can create`service` object via

```
$client_and_token = getClient();
$service = new Google\Service\Drive($client_and_token['client']);
```

Then, to set up `Google Drive Push Notifications`, if I follow instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push

I am led to believe, the correct approach is

```
$httpclient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$body = [
    'id' => uniqid(),
    'kind' => "drive#changes",
    'type' => 'web_hook',
    'address' => 'https://myendpoint'
];

$token = $client_and_token['token'];
$apiendpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch';
$result = $httpclient->post($apiendpoint, [
                                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => "Bearer {$token}"],
                                'body' => json_encode($body),
                                "http_errors" => false]);
```

Apparently, thanks to reading here:

[Get Google Analytics API token / Google_Client getAccessToken returns null / empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62424929/get-google-analytics-api-token-google-client-getaccesstoken-returns-null-emp)

that `$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();` part is key to getting this to work with service account, as opposed to the method shown here -https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php - about PHP Quickstart, which assumes user interaction from what I can tell, as the means to receive the token. In any case, with token received, as per the documentation, you have to add to the header

```
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
```

Above ends up returning error about missing parameter `pageToken`. By the way, anyone using `new \GuzzleHttp\Client()` might notice truncated errors, making it hard to figure out what on earth is going on. At first I was only seeing `missing parameter: p` because rest was truncated! Hence above I add `"http_errors" => false`, and then see entire in `$contents = $result->getBody()->getContents();`

In reading the watch push documentation

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch

I don't see anything about `pageToken` being required param.

But looks like it is needed, so after reading here

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-changes

I get the initial `pageToken` using that `$service` object from above, via

```
$response = $service->changes->getStartPageToken();
$startpagetoken = $response->startPageToken;
```

Then I do the Push POST to set up the channel notifications as

```
$apiendpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch?pageToken='.$startpagetoken;
$result = $httpclient->post($apiendpoint, [
                                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => "Bearer {$token}"],
                                'body' => json_encode($body),
                                "http_errors" => false]);
```

Now everything works. Granted, I probably need to think about when to refresh the token, etc, and figure out what to do with subsequent pageTokens, but glad I finally got past all these hurdles.

I suspect a lot of people go through this misery, especially those using PHP for this sort of server-to-server no login, no user interaction authentication method.

In summary, to get all this working:

1. **Follow steps to enable Google Drive API, validate a domain, register domain in search console. Those steps are here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push**. Note, you can even get this working on localhost on your local computer. I am using `ngrok` on a Mac, and so in following steps above, I use my `ngrok` provided URL, but of course you have to make sure your site is not open to the public. I am still not sure best way to do that. I am for now using `no-follow` in meta tag in `<head>`, but I am sure I need to do something else in my local Apache config (maybe someone has idea?).
2. **Set up service account as shown here:** https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account. A lot of articles about service accounts get out of control quickly. You don't have to do all sorts of nonsense with the account. Just add role for the email address tied to the service account. So if you have something like `name@app.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as the service account email, then make sure this user has a sufficiently high role in the account (like Owner). And not sure if it is needed, but for the folder I am trying to watch for changes, I added `name@app.iam.gserviceaccount.com` in the list of users with share access. As part of this process, you end up with a json file with the service account credentials. This is what I use above in `$client->setAuthConfig( __DIR__  . '/serviceaccount.json');`
3. **Make the necessary Push HTTP requests**, depending on what you need to do, be it `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch` (plus the annoying pageToken!), to get your endpoint set to receive the notifs.
4. **In your notification endpoint, do whatever you need to do**, for instance, I am using my Google Drive Push Notifications so that when I save a Zoom video to my Google Drive, I notify users on my WordPress site who have access to the video. This is my way of not paying Zoom the extra fee for Zoom Record to Cloud feature. I just hit Record button in Zoom, then when done save the video to my Google Drive. So in WordPress, this is done as

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'mytheme/v1', '/googledrivesave', array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'googledrivesave',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
    ) );
}

function googledrivesave (WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $headers= getallheaders();
    // do stuff
    return http_response_code(200);
}
```

In Laravel etc, would be similar approach.